# Gradle sync failed: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable in android studio

Tags: android

Please Help, Android studio is not working and this error is comes.
I also reinstall the android studio but same error is comes.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution of the my problem.

- Uninstall Android studio totally from the system.
- Restart the system.
- Go to C:\Users\
- Delete .android, .AndroidStudio2.3, .gradle folders. If folder not deleted then change the name of this folder.
- Now, Reinstall the android studio.

And then you problem will solved. This is work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution there no need to Uninstall Android studio simply We need to do only one thing :

> go to "file" and click on "Invalid caches\ Restart" option.

Answer (score 1):

Don't uninstall your Android studio.

Rather try Like @Anjali has suggested.

> go to "file" and click on "Invalid caches\ Restart" option.

If it doesn't work, close your Android studio and

> Delete .android, .AndroidStudio2.3, .gradle folders. If any folder is not deleted then change the name of that folder.

And simply restart your Android studio. It has worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to uninstall Android Studio and maybe an issue occurs during the Gradle build time and Gradle cannot load data in the metadata folder or you have multiple data folder in the Gradle file.

Follow the below steps

1. Go to `"C:\Users\PC\.gradle\caches\modules-2"`
2. Close the Android Studio
3. Delete any metadata folder available from that listing or you can delete or rename the metadata folder as per your project given the error.
4. Start the android studio and ensuring that you have internet connections
5. Wait for Gradle to download some files and sync then
6. Everything should work well after doing that

I have followed the above steps and got success.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this issue solved by just restarting my machine. My project was on 'D:' drive and this drive was getting corrupted and showing a message like 'unable to read files system'.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete this file manually from `Linux` if you have it installed alongside windows

Answer (score 0):

In my case this issue solved by just:
1- Open This PC, right-click the partition you want to scan, and choose Properties from the menu.
2- Navigate to Tools tab and click the Check button.
3- Check Automatically fix system errors and click Start.